# How do we sort a 2D string array using std::sort in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

I've tried it using the following piece of code but it gave an error. However, the same piece of code runs fine on a 2D integer array.

Code:
sort(str[i], str[i]+4); // i is the looping iterator for the string

Error:

> [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::string {aka
>   std::basic_string}' and 'int')

Comment: Fix the code please. It seems cutoff.

Comment: use 4 spaces for code, and please take a look at the preview before posting (can help to avoid unnecessary downvotes)

Comment: And when you fix the code, please make it a [mcve] - enough that anyone can compile and reproduce the error, but without anything that's not directly relevant to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: std::sort does not have a template-less overload. how did you use it without specifying template parameters?

Comment: Show us the definition of `str`, the whole loop, and preferably the `int[][]` code that you were using. The error message there suggests you have `std::string str[]`. Are you trying to sort the letters in each string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Documentation [**std::sort**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order. The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved.

### Definition

`template< class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp )`

### Parameters

> **first**, **last**   -   the range of elements to sort
>
> **comp**  -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

**Complexity**: **`O(N·log(N))`** where *N* = `std::distance(first, last)`

**Note**: Its better to use `vector` than `array`, specially in your case(*2D strings*).

*Example:*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void printTwoDString(vector< vector<string> > twodString){
    for(int i = 0; i < twodString.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < twodString[i].size(); j++)
            cout<<twodString[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector< vector<string> > twodString = {
        {"chandler", "joey", "janice"},
        {"gunther", "richard", "rachel"},
        {"monika", "phoebe", "ross"}
    };

    // sort the whole string
    std::sort(twodString.begin(), twodString.end());
    printTwoDString(twodString);

    // sort a single row (should sort second row to gunther rachel richard )
    std::sort(twodString[1].begin(), twodString[1].end());
    printTwoDString(twodString);
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Code**](https://ideone.com/6DU24A)